# Userform controls - looping and checking value

Tags: excel, vba, controls, userform, togglebutton

I am trying to loop through two sets of controls on a userform. If a combination of two controls (togglebuttons) are true then do something. The sub is called from the userform where the controls are created. This is the first time I've used the userform control variable, the code below won't compile so this is probably completely wrong. Any suggestions please?

Updated the code sample, but I am getting a compile error. See image below:

[image: compile error]

```
Private Sub CONTROLS_Click()
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
Dim BOOK As Variant, STRAT As Variant

BOOK = Array("TYPE1", "TYPE2")
STRAT = Array("FAST", "MEDIUM", "SLOW")


For X = LBound(BOOK) To UBound(BOOK)
    If Me.CONTROLS(BOOK(X)).Value = True Then
        For Y = LBound(STRAT) To UBound(STRAT)
             If Me.CONTROLS(STRAT(Y)).Value = True Then
                'DO SOMETHING
            End If
        Next Y
    End If
Next X


End Sub
```

Comment: The fact that `Me.CONTROLS(...)` remains in upper case instead of the VBE's auto-correction making it `Me.Controls(..)` the way it should be concerns me. It is like you've used **CONTROLS** as the name for something and you have overwritten its reserved use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are each an array of 1.

```
BOOK = Array("TYPE1, TYPE2")
STRAT = Array("FAST,MEDIUM,SLOW")
```

They should be,

```
BOOK = Array("TYPE1", "TYPE2")
STRAT = Array("FAST", "MEDIUM", "SLOW")
```

Variant arrays are typically zero-based; the first element in the BOOK array is at BOOK(0). They use a *1* based index when filled directly off a worksheet for if redimmed explicitly to start at 1. Best to use the [LBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) to determien the Lower and Upper Boundaries all of the time.

```
 Private Sub CONTROLS_Click()
    Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
    Dim BOOK As Variant, STRAT As Variant

    'Type1, Type2, Fast, Medium and Slow are the names of the togglebuttons
    BOOK = Array("TYPE1", "TYPE2")
    STRAT = Array("FAST", "MEDIUM", "SLOW")

    For X = LBound(BOOK) To UBound(BOOK)
        If Me.CONTROLS(BOOK(X)).Value = True Then
            For Y = LBound(STRAT) To UBound(STRAT)
                 If Me.CONTROLS(STRAT(Y)).Value = True Then
                    'DO SOMETHING
                End If
            Next Y
        End If
    Next X

 End Sub
```

That should fix your array assignment and nested `For ... Next` loops.

Comment: @Zeus - Somehow the BOOK declaration got turned to BOOK_COMP making all of the other uses of BOOK invalid. Don't know how it happened but I've rectified it now.

Comment: I spotted that also, and changed it, but I still get the compile error even with the correction. I'm sure this can be done....any ideas why it won't compile?

Comment: I found the problem. One of the listboxes was called CONTROLS and caused the compile error. Code now working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like I was right to suspect a rogue naming. Glad to hear you isolated the problem and resolved the issue!